# android mathematical calculations in eclipse java

Tags: android, math

Can anybody tell me why the result of the following expression is -4.91679930495

```
9.81*Math.cos(phi)/Math.sin(phi)
```

if phi = 90°?

In particular, I want to display the value of acceleration.

```
tvText2.setText("acceleration: " + String.valueOf(9.81*Math.cos(phi)/Math.sin(phi)) + " m/s²");
```

Comment: probably because the Math.cos and Math.sin take radians instead of degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos(double):

The paremeter of those methods is in radians.

you will need to call `Math.toRadians` that receives an angle in degrees.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I really didn't know that. But it isn't much better if I use Math.toRadians. Look at that: 9.81*(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(phi)))/(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(phi)))   Thix expression delivers 6.00689254981

Comment: What should be the expetect result? 0?

Comment: @user3137385 Notice that that 6.00 result is rounded, notice the `E-16`. That's almost 0. I suggest you read something about `floating point`.

Comment: That's it! My TextView was too small. I didn't see the E-16! :) Now I've got my zero. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Every language I know of uses radians in trigonometric functions: FORTRAN, C, C++, Java, C#, JavaScript.  How do people continue to use degrees?

Answer (score 0):

Convert phi to Radian before calculating acceleration:

```
double phiInRad = Math.toRadians(phi);

tvText2.setText("acceleration: " + String.valueOf(9.81*Math.cos(phiInRad)/Math.sin(phiInRad)) + " m/s²");
```

or in one line

```
  tvText2.setText("acceleration: " + String.valueOf(9.81*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(phi))/Math.sin(Math.toRadians(phi))) + " m/s²");
```

Comment: That's really strange. Math.toRadians works but if phi is almost 90° the result changes to 6.00...